# URL as barcode (not QR)

Tags: barcode, barcode-printing

QR codes are great for printing machine readable URLs if you have a square space. But they look horrible if placed in a text as they are much taller than a line of text.

Is there a way I can have a 1d-barcode with the same functionality as QR code (URL being the most important feature) so it can be put as text in a normal paragraph without special formatting?

If yes: How do I generate those barcodes?

Comment: You can, but the barcode will have to be a lot longer to provide enough storage.  A UPC barcode only encodes 12 numerical digits, not text.  http://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/articles/barcode_basics  Scroll down to "How much data can you actually encode?"  Storage capacity is why 2d barcodes exist.  They can store a lot more.

Comment: Since google/ddg wasn't helpful, I tried a hundred different types from https://barcode.tec-it.com but **the Apple camera will only scan QR codes and nothing else.** No data matrix, no bar code, no mail codes, no payment codes, no mini qr, nothing. If compatibility with such wheelchaired devices is required (these people probably don't know how to install a better app anyway), you'll have to stick with the regular QR codes and can't use 1D barcodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There're different barcode symbologies that can encode text. The main problem is how much text you want to encode and which apps are you going to use to decode the barcode.

If you're using an URL shortener and you want to stick to a 1D barcode, [CODE128](https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/CODE128) is probably the best choice.

Another option could be a [PDF417](https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/PDF417), it's a 2D barcode but is not square like QRCode. In this case you can encode more chars in less space and this symbology is supported by iOS and the major Barcodes library.

Comment: The PDF417 link is dead. Alternative link: https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/PDF417

Comment: Thanks for the ping!
I updated both links to the website you sent.